# Не работает "transition" при ивенте "mouseout"

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>JS #4 | Hover Board</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container" id="board"></div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
    background: url(https://cutewallpaper.org/25/anime-desktop-wallpaper-loop/1001212984.jpg);
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 480px;
    background-image: url("https://static1.personality-database.com/profile_images/e2b5e6939128414fbbfffd95ac36d843.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 12px rgb(182, 136, 136);
}

.square {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: #1d1d1d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3.5px rgb(182, 136, 136);
    transition: 4s ease;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.square:hover {
    transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

JS:

```
const board = document.querySelector("#board")
const colors = ["#ff00ff", "#ff00b3", "#ff005d", "#ff0022", "#e172e7"]
const SQUARES_NUMBER = 225
const body = document.querySelector("body")

for (let i = 0; i < SQUARES_NUMBER; i++) {
    const square = document.createElement("div")
    square.classList.add("square")

    board.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
        body.style.background = "url(https://cutewallpaper.org/25/anime-desktop-wallpaper-loop/1001212984.jpg)"
        body.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed"
        body.style.backgroundSize = "cover"
        body.style.transition = "4s ease"
    })

    square.addEventListener("mouseover", setColor)

    square.addEventListener("mouseleave", removeColor)

    board.append(square)
}

function setColor(event) {
    const element = event.target
    const color = getRandomColor()
    element.style.backgroundColor = color
    element.style.boxShadow = `0 0 16px ${color}`

    setTimeout(() => {
        element.classList.add("appeared")
    }, 0)

    if (element.classList.contains("appeared")) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = "#1d1d1d00"
        element.style.boxShadow = `0 0 0 #1d1d1d00`
    }

    // body
    body.style.background = color
}

function removeColor(event) {
    const element = event.target
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#1d1d1d00"
    element.style.boxShadow = `0 0 0 #1d1d1d00`
    element.style.transform = "scale(0)"
}

function getRandomColor() {
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
}
```

Код в редакторе, на всякий случай:  https://jsfiddle.net/5na1msj9/

**~**
Нужно что б в этой строке отображался `body.style.transition = "4s ease"`, хотя он уже и так прописан в css, работает **только** при смене **цвета фона** при наведении на кнопки.

```
board.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
        body.style.background = "url(https://cutewallpaper.org/25/anime-desktop-wallpaper-loop/1001212984.jpg)"
        body.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed"
        body.style.backgroundSize = "cover"
        body.style.transition = "4s ease"
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Анимировать при помощи transition можно только числовые свойства, такие как top, left, margin, padding, width, opacity и пр. Это связано с тем, что браузер может плавно изменять значения таких свойств, изменяя их на сотые и десятые доли. Нечисловые свойства, такие как display, position и ваш background-image, не могут быть плавно изменены при помощи transition, поскольку между например display: block и display: none нет никакого промежуточного состояния.
Все цвета в Вебе могут быть преобразованы в шестнадцатеричный формат (HEX), то есть могут быть представлены как числа, а значит могут анимироваться при помощи transition.

Comment: Благодарю за долгое объяснение

Answer (score 0):

> Не работает "transition" при ивенте "mouseout"

свойство background-image не является анимируемым. Поэтому можно заменить картинку просто на однородный фон. Тогда будет срабатывать transition. Или немного изменить логику, и пробовать с `opacity`

Comment: Спасибо, понял.

Comment: пожалуйста, если ответ был полезным - кликнете стрелку вверх, слева от ответа.